# ObjectionJS: HasMany Relation over two fields of child

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, objection.js

I am currently working with Objection get nice objects out of a SQL query.

I have a match like this:

```
id integer primary key,
teamA integer references(teams.id),
teamB integer references(teams.id),

scoreA integer,
scoreB integer
```

Is there a way in my Objection `Team` class to specify that my team has `matches`, so `HasMany` relation, but can be found in two fields.

Such as

```js
  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      matches: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: Match,
        join: {
          from: ['matches.teamA', 'matches.teamB'],
          to: 'teams.id',
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are approaching the modelling little differently.
By looking at your table's its evident that it's an `m:n` relationship i.e. One match has many (2 to be precise) teams and one team can play many matches. So here you need third table for joining them and create relationships accordingly.